# Get the max height in a llist

Tags: javascript, jquery, height, each

I have a big list. With a lot of list items. I try to make a script. That get the highest li item. And than put the highest li item, on all the items.

```
$('.list li').each(function() {
    var listHeight = $(this).outerHeight();

    $(this).css({ height: listHeight + 'px' })
});
```

So I would like the highest li item. And then. This height at all places li items. How can i fix that. Who can help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var maxHeight = -1;
$('.list li').each(function() {
     maxHeight = maxHeight > $(this).height() ? maxHeight : $(this).height();
})
.height(maxHeight);
```